# $rootScope.$broadcast is failing when fallback language is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translation

Implementing localization in angular app.
In app.js, written below code to support fallback language , if required .json files not present in the specific {{de-DE}}\ folder. (Taken german for example)

```js
function configure($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $translateProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider) {
$routeProvider            
            .when('/instructions', {
                templateUrl: "app/instructions/Instructions.html",
                resolve: {
                    translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('instructions');
                        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('common');
                      

                        //$translatePartialLoader.addPart('instructions').then(function (data) {
                            //console.log(data);
                        //});
                        //$translatePartialLoader.addPart('common').then(function (data) {
                          //  console.log(data);
                        //});

                        $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage("en-US");
                        return $translate.refresh();
                    }]
                }
            })            
          .otherwise(
                {
                    redirectTo: redirectTo
                });

        $httpProvider.useApplyAsync(true);



        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage($("#CultureCode").val());
        $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en-US');
  }
```

After changing my browser setting to german (google chrome). Files were not found, so it had to fallback. With the above code, my fallback language was english. So app downloaded .json files from  {{en-US}}\folder.

But the actual problem is.

Once all the code excecutes , in one place i have written.

```js
  $rootScope.$broadcast("SHIFT_CHANGED");
```

And subscribing for the event like below.

```js
$scope.$on("SHIFT_CHANGED", function() {

  loadInstructions();
});
```

Here load instructions in my main method. Which is not getting executed because. Shift_changed events is not getting fired.

For testing purpose as soon as i paste those .json files in german folder. App starts working. But am trying to implement fallback.

I tried few code which is commented for refrence above. addpart trying to resolve for promise.

But none of them worked.

Am i missing some thing. And no error in console.

clueless to figure out.Any ideas to troubleshoot further / Is really some code is missing.

Please help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: .josn files ?? ... it looks strange

Comment: Yes for localization purpose setting key value pair in .json files File content is like below.
{

"Success": "Success",
"Warning": "Warning",
"Info": "Info",
"An_Error_Occurred":  "An Error Occurred",
"No_schedulestartdate":"Please provide Schedule startdate"
}

Comment: during transalation values will be transalted to german. And those new files will be placed in {{de-DE}}\ folder

Comment: ok but you wrote  
.josn files not json .. is only a type here or also in your project?

Comment: sorry typo error, will correct it now @federicoscamuzzi Thanks